# Play next video on button click in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, video, avplayer, avplayeritem

I have 2 videos. I am using AVPlayer to play videos. The first one is loaded when App starts, and when I click on the next video, it should start playing that video from the start. How can it be done?

I am using the following code in attempt to switch to the next video

```
AVPlayerItem * playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    [self pause];
    [self.moviePlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    [self.moviePlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [self play];
```